# Thread try catch continue if access to file was denied

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, file-permissions, permission-denied

Looping through a folder using system thread, how to ignore and continue if access to file was denied.

```
// Start thread.  
System.Threading.ThreadStart start = delegate { scanner(@"C:\", "*.html;*.txt"); };
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(start);
thread.Start();


private static string scanstatus = string.Empty;
private static void scanner(string folder, string patterns) 
{
    try
    {  
        // Get the patterns.
        string[] pattern_array = patterns.Split(';');

        // Search.
        foreach (string pattern in pattern_array)
        {
            foreach (string path in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, pattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                // trim path
                scanstatus = (path.Length > 60) ? "../" + path.Substring(path.Length - 59, 59) : path;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*************DONE*************");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with putting a `try-catch` inside the loop?

Comment: it doesn't continue. I'm not sure what i do wrong

Comment: You need to put the `try-catch` **inside** the loop. You have it **outside** the loop...

Comment: It is because your loop is inside the try catch.When access denied exception raised the flow of program transfer to the catch which is out from your loop.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14402/Testing-File-Access-Rights-in-NET-2-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in the comment, basically when you want to keep going with the next iteration, you need to move the try/catch to inside the loop. Currently your catch is *outside* the outer loop, so if an exception is thrown, execution can't continue. There's no concept of "continue from where you'd got to" within C#.

I'd strongly suggest that you *also* limit what you catch. For example:

```
foreach (string pattern in patternArray)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(...))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Log it or whatever
    }
    // Any other exceptions you want to catch?
}
```

Notes:

- Catching `Exception` is almost always a bad idea, except as a final backstop at the top level of your request (or whatever) handling
- Underscores in variable names aren't conventional in .NET; typically you'd use camelCase for variables (and PascalCase for methods, classes etc)
- With `using` directives you can avoid putting the fully-qualified type names in your code, which would make it much easier to read
- This method will end up being quite long - I'd suggest extracting the inner loop; possibly including the try/catch, or possibly not.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In particular with Excel files, this line just hangs and the exception isn't raised: `wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true,5,null,"WrongPAssword");`. Do you know how to test if you have permission?

Comment: @Power-Mosfet: Well what *does* it do? If the exception is thrown, it *will* continue to the next thread.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: I don't see what Excel has to do with this question. The OP certainly never mentioned it. The way the question is phrased certainly *implies* that an exception is thrown.